# How to change a function passed as a prop to React component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to build a reusable SnackBar (little popup displaying info of what just happened) component with **optional** UNDO action. I would like to use it like this:

## Main component

```
import SnackBar from "./SnackBar";
import { useState } from "react";

const MainComponent({item}) => {
        const [snackBarVisible, setSnackBarVisible] = useState(false);
        const [snackBarMessage, setSnackBarMessage] = useState("");
        const [undoFunction , setUndoFunction ] = useState(null);
        //var undoFunction = null;

        const undoAddToFav = () => {
                //code that removes from favorites the stuff that was just added 
                console.log("removed last added product from favs");
        };

        const undoAddToCart = () => {
                //code that removes from cart the last added product
                console.log("removed last added product from cart");
        }

        const addToCart = (item) => {
                //some code
                setSnackBarMessage("Item added to cart");
                //HELP NEEDED HERE
                //undoFunction = undoAddToCart; // this doesn't work at all (no error messages)
                setUndoFunction(() => undoAddToCart()) // this executes undoAddToCart when addToCart is called and not on button press
                setSnackBarVisible(true);
        }
        const addToFavorites = (item) => {
                //some code
                setSnackBarMessage("Item added to favourites");
                //undoFunction = undoAddToFav ; // <== HELP NEEDED HERE
                //setUndoFunction(() => undoAddToCart()) 
                setSnackBarVisible(true);
        }
        const displaySnackBar = () => {
                setSnackBarMessage("Some info");
                setSnackBarVisible(true);
                //this one has no "undo" button
        }
        //some other stuff
        return (
                //some other stuff that calls the actions above
                <SnackBar snackBarMessage = {snackBarMessage} snackBarVisible = {snackBarVisible) undoFunction = {undoFunction}/>
        );
};
```

### Child component

I'd like this undo action to be optional.

```
export default const SnackBar = ({snackBarMessage, snackBarVisible, undoFunction}) => {
        //some stuff
        return (
                <>                
                        //some stuff - handle visibility, etc
                        //help needed here as well - how do I display the button only when the function prop is passed?
                        {undoFunction && <button onClick={undoFunction}>UNDO</button>}; //this doesn't work properly
                        <div>{snackBarMessage}</div>;
                </>
        );
};
```

I've tried useState, useCallback, useMemo, useRef to handle this and nothing seems to work. This is my first cry for help here :)

[image: Edit gracious-keller-ixbcuk]

Answer (score 0):

You must declare `undoFunction` using `useState`, ex by default null:

`const [undoFunction, setUndoFunction] = useState(null)`

And then use `setUndoFunction(/* your new function here or null */)`.

It didn't work because if you don't use a state, React won't re-render changes.

Comment: Edited the question. This still doesn't work. UNDO button is not being displayed at all, so undoFunction remains null I guess.

Comment: Can't you set undoFunction's initial value to true instead of null?

Comment: @KasRoudra I want UNDO button not to display by default. Only some notifications have UNDO action. I'm trying to find a way to display the button only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for your question starts from `MainComponent`

```
const [undoFunction , setUndoFunction ] = useState(null);
```

Since the value of `undoFunction` is null, the button won't render at all in the child component. I mean this code.

```
{undoFunction && <button onClick={undoFunction}>UNDO</button>}; //this doesn't work properly
```

You can change it to something like this. Render the button and execute `undoFunction` if that's available.

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
    if (undoFunction) undoFunction();
  }}
>
UNDO
</button>
```

I have made a simple [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-wescoff-g8fnox?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) for this functionality. I've used an extra button for passing undo functionality. Check the code and see how you can use.

Comment: Thanks for help, but there is still a problem with this one. I want "UNDO" button to display only when needed. I made couple of changes to your sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/red-firefly-muu6xk?file=/src/SnackBar.js). When I click "Undo snackbar" and then "No undo snackbar" the button is still there.